# Macintosh XCode Sharing

Tags: macos, sharing, remote-access

I got a macbook pro and I want to share it with some of my friend located at the other side of internet. He can use Internet.

Now I want him to give access to my whole Macbook (XCode for most) so he can do developments at his location using my macbook. Now I need to ask is there a way we can both utilize the samme macbook having two virtual OS (one for me and one for him) without affecting each others' privacy?

Is it possible to share the macbook across more than 1 user? I don't mean Remote Desktop like of thing in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear by "Xcode sharing" whether you mean share the source code and split development efforts (ie, your friend has his own Mac with Xcode at the other end of the Internet) or whether you mean that you need him to actually use Xcode on your machine through the Internet.

If you mean share the source code, that is easy: Xcode has versioning control built in. Use that. Or you can use one of the many other code control systems that are common for this use. Subversion is one. [There are many.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

If by "Xcode sharing" you mean some form of screen sharing over the Internet, you can do this: set up a new account on your Mac that that does not have access to your account. This is not bullet proof, but if you are "friends" there must be some trust there. To set up a new account, go to System Preferences / Accounts. You can also use [FileVault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) on your account if you wish. Then allow your friend to VNC to the account that you created.

I think the performance of screen sharing over the Internet to run Xcode will leave you both bald after you have torn your last hairs out in frustration. It will be slow and low res. You can't use the computer while your friend is using it. You friend will have a lousy development environment.

Have your friend buy a used Mac, use [Subversion](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html) or [CVS](http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/cvsoverview.html), and save your hair...

Another possibility: Limit your friend's efforts to text only, and use ssh and gcc. You then can roll his efforts into the overall project using Xcode.

Comment: HaHa. Well there is a high need to share the screen, mouse and keyboard of particular user on MAC to my friend. We both have pretty fast internet connection so it won't be that lousy.

Comment: It is pretty lousy even on a high-speed local gigabit lan. Have you tried it?

Comment: As a note for going shell-only, I'll point out that Xcode installs the Xcodebuild command-line utility, which you may find useful...

Answer (score 0):

You could give him ssh access, but then he couldn't use Xcode. You could give him VNC access, but that's the Remote Desktop like of thing that you didn't want. Also, with VNC, you couldn't both use the computer at the same time.

As for privacy, you can give him his own user account. But you'd have to find some way to configure VNC so it's running at the login window. I'm not sure how to do this or if it can be done, but it sounds like something that should be possible.

You will find the options for VNC ("Screen Sharing") and SSH ("Remote Login") under the sharing pane of System Preferences.

Comment: what if I use TeamViewer? I know I can share screen using TeamViewer but can I share mouse and keyboard as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

This kind of sharing is possible via VNC which is tunneled through SSH. Just Google VNC over SSH and you will get lots of tutorials. I have tried this on a lan and it works well.

Over the internet you need to have a Dynamic DNS service if you do not have a static external IP and you need to port forward the SSH port(i.e. port 22) on your home router.

I have used TeamViewer in the past for this but there is a BIG problem with it, when we drag buttons to the code area to link them and generate code a blue line should show up in xcode depicting the link, but it does not show this blue line when done via TeamViewer for some reason and that link cannot be made.